# Selenium code inside Odoo WebDriverException

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, odoo, containers

I'm trying to run a simple selenium code in method in odoo 16 that i installed in container with button on my form view.

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

d = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver')
d.get("http://localhost:8069/web/database/manager")
```

I installed selenium,web_driver,chrome browser... in the container of odoo with these commands :

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y libgconf-2-4
apt-get install -y chromium-driver
pip3 install selenium
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
apt-get -f install
```

(version of chorme browser and chromedriver 112)
i added this line in dockerfile (ENV Selenium_UseHeadlessDriver=true)
i make the limit_memory_hard = 9999999999

but where i run selenium code in interface it return this error:

```
    raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self.path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -5
```

i expect to find solution to run the selenium code from odoo, thanks a lot for your time